# Date Time Picker Functionality with user input interface changed. WINFORM

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I want to use date time picker for my window application. I am using `Min Date` `Max Date` property in my code. But user interface for inputing date is very complex for the purpose of accounting where we need faster typing speed and no or very less use of mouse.

I want to modify a user interface for date time picker such that user need to type 24012010 for 24/01/2010.

What i need to do for this. Or is it their any dll or some other tool which can provide me all the functionalities of date time picker with this functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx). There's a good example on that page which will make sure the user has only entered numbers for their date. You'll then have to make sure the numbers form a valid date (i.e. not 99/99/9999) with your own validation code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party controls for such a thing - we have been using DevExpress controls for about 4 years and are pretty happy :-).